# Disable auto complete text in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

for example if i write a text:
`(` then i get auto `()`,

next example:
`"` then i get auto complete by vs: `""`

how could i disable this *function* in visual studio 2013?

i would stay only with ("an exception") for `{`

i know now that i can disable it with:

`Tools -> options -> text editor -> general and the option: automatic brace completion`

but now i would add extension for `{`, that it can be complete in vs for result `{}`

Comment: You can't partially disable brace completion, if that's what you're looking for. You could disable it completely and write your own completion provider for `{`, but it's non-trivial (has to handle return properly with smart indentation, etc.) Have a look at [`IBraceCompletionContextProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.bracecompletion.ibracecompletioncontextprovider.aspx) if you really want to go that route.

Answer (score 1):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > General

Uncheck `Automatic brace completion`

I've tested this on Visual Studio 2013.

This will turn off all auto-completions.  There doesn't seem to be an option to add an exception.

Comment: I've updated my answer and tested it out this time :)